# Many to Many data-structure in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, many-to-many

I was wondering how I could implement a many-to-many relationship data-structure. Or if something like this already exists in the wild.

What I would need is two groups of objects, where members from one group are relating to multiple members of the other group. And vice versa.
I also need the structure to have some sort of consistency, meaning members without any connections are dropped, or basically cannot exist.

I have seen this answer (it involves SQL-lite database), but I am not working with such huge volumes of objects, so it's not an appropriate answer for this context [Many-to-many data structure in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538322/many-to-many-data-structure-in-python)

Comment: I think [that linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538322/many-to-many-data-structure-in-python) is certainly an appropriate answer. Do yourself a favor and try that.

Comment: I am looking for something simpler. Since this would usually be a 10 to 10 relation, and a 50 to 50 at the most pessimistic extreme.
Making an SQL database, seems quite an overhead.
But, thanks for the input.

Comment: You might have to build your own custom data structure that has a member for storing references to other ones

Comment: I see. Yeah, was just wondering if something like this already exists or if there is a common pattern to use. I could do it like Anne recommended using a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how big your dataset is, you could simply build all possible sets and then assign booleans to see whether the relationship exists.

```
itertools.combinations
```

can be of help to generate all possible combinations.
Consistency can then be added by checking if any connections are `True` for each value.
 I do not claim this is the prettiest approach, but it should work on smaller datasets.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: That's a good idea. If there is no better way I think I will go with that one.