# Python app to organise ideas by tags

Tags: python, logic, tagging

Please give me a hint about how is it better to code a Python application which helps to organise ideas by tags.

**Add a new idea:**

Input 1: the idea

Input 2: corresponding tags

**Search for the idea:**

Input 1: one or multiple tags

As far as I understood, it's necessary to create an array with ideas and an array with tags. But how to connect them? For example, idea number 3 corresponds to tags number 1 and 2. So the question is: how to link these two arrays in the most simple and elegant way?

Comment: Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538322/many-to-many-data-structure-in-python

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include a [mcve] of your problem. A code block defining what an "idea" object should look like would be a good start, but anything that you've attempted to try and solve this would also help us steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @Moberg. If it wasn't for the difference of scale, I'd close as a duplicate. I doubt anyone is going to record anything close to 10^5 ideas. But then again you never know.

Answer (score 0):

Have two dictionaries:

1. Idea -> Set of Tags
2. Tag -> Set of Ideas

When you add a new idea, add it to the first dictionary, and then update all the sets of the tags it uses in the second dictionary. This way you get easy lookup by both tag and idea.

Answer (score -1):

Python sequential data structures are called `list`s. while it is a good idea to use them you should probably look at `dict`s.

If you are unfamiliar with the `dict` data structure I would recommend going through a quick Python tutorial, but generally they can be used with a `list` to solve your problem:

```
ideas = []

def record_idea(idea_text, tag):
    idea = dict(text=idea_text, tags=tags)
    ideas.append(idea)

def fetch_by_tag(tag):
    for idea in ideas:
        if tag in idea['tags']:
            print(idea['text'])
```

of course if you use this with a CLI you should save and load your ideas from a file. I am sure you can find a lot resources about that on the internet

Comment: Thanks a lot, Doron!

Comment: @MadPhysicist your comment isn't useful. care to explain?

Comment: @ZenBerry if this answer fits you please consider accepting it

Comment: You are not using the fact that dicts allow you to do constant time lookup, and are instead using them as containers for simple object attributes. A better usage might be to map tags to ideas and vice versa. Dicts allow you to avoid linear searches, like the one you're doing. The dicts you have could be equally well served by a two-element tuple.

Comment: `dict`s *allow* you constant time lookup, you don't have to use it. I don't see how a tuple is better here, @ZenBerry is trying to organize his data not get a list of tuples of attributes. If you'd say `namedtuple`s that I can understand but I think he was looking for a simple solution.